# How to fetch records from different table without join and Subquery

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My Database Relational Schema

```
DEPARTMENT(deptnum, descrip, instname, deptname, state, postcode)
ACADEMIC(acnum, deptnum*, famname, givename, initials, title)
PAPER(panum, title)
AUTHOR(panum*, acnum*)
FIELD(fieldnum, id, title)
INTEREST(fieldnum*, acnum*, descrip)
```

I need to get the paper that have authors from different department without using Join and subquery

Comment: Why not join or subquery?

Comment: Call authors on the phone and ask them would be one option.

Comment: @Littlefoot, This was actually ROFL....

Comment: Matches the question, @Ankit :)